# Why is catching checked exceptions allowed for code that does not throw exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, checked-exceptions, unchecked-exception

In Java, methods that throw **checked** exceptions ([Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) or its subtypes - IOException, InterruptedException, etc) must declare **throws** statement:

```
public abstract int read() throws IOException;
```

Methods that do not declare `throws` statement **can't** throw checked exceptions.

```
public int read() { // does not compile
    throw new IOException();
}
// Error: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

But catching checked exceptions in safe methods is still legal in java:

```
public void safeMethod() { System.out.println("I'm safe"); }

public void test() { // method guarantees not to throw checked exceptions
    try {
        safeMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) { // catching checked exception java.lang.Exception
        throw e; // so I can throw... a checked Exception?
    }
}
```

Actually, no. It's a bit funny: compiler knows that **e** is not a checked exception and allows to rethrow it. Things are even a bit ridiculous, this code does not compile:

```
public void test() { // guarantees not to throw checked exceptions
    try {
        safeMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) {        
        throw (Exception) e; // seriously?
    }
}
// Error: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

The first snippet was a motivation for a question.

Compiler knows that checked exceptions can't be thrown inside a safe method - so maybe it should allow to catch only unchecked exceptions?

---

Returning to the **main question** - are there any reasons to implement catching checked exceptions in this way? Is it just a flaw in the design or am I missing some important factors - maybe backward incompatibilities?  What could potentially go wrong if only `RuntimeException` were allowed to be catched in this scenario? Examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the main question: It is not a flaw in the design per se, RuntimeExceptions are subclasses of Exception, therefore catching Exception also includes unchecked exceptions.
That being said, there is no reason do to it like this, it might even confuse people reading the code because they might think safeMethod() might throw an Exception.
I think just catching RuntimeException here is a better choice.

Comment: [Relevant section of the JLS on the throw statement.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18)

Comment: You can even catch `Throwable` too. What's wrong with catching a more general type?

Comment: @bayou.io it's the same as why to use generics if we could use raw types? And the answer is stronger compiler checks. Compiler can tell that Exception can't be thrown but only RuntimeException, so why catch it?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker We know the many problems raw types cause. What problem does catching a wider type cause? This is why your metaphor breaks down. By your argument `final Object ob = "foo";` should result in a compiler error too, because we know at compile time that the runtime type of `ob` will be `String`.

Comment: @biziclop I agree with this.

Comment: Since `safeMethod()` is, well, safe, that means that the caught `Exception e` **must be** a `RuntimeException`. If it is left as-is (as in the first snippet) all is well. But when you explicitly cast to `Exception` in the second snippet you make the compiler forget what it knows and believe that it could be any `Exception`, which of course is not ok.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting the [Java Language Specification, §11.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E1, unless E1 is Exception or a superclass of Exception.

I'm guessing that this rule originated long before Java 7, where multi-catches did not exist. Therefore, if you had a `try` block that could throw a multitude of exceptions, the easiest way to catch everything would be to catch a common superclass (in the worst case, `Exception`, or `Throwable` if you want to catch `Error`s as well).

Note that you may *not* catch an exception type that is completely unrelated to what is actually thrown - in your example, catching any subclass of `Throwable` that is not a `RuntimeException` will be an error:

```
try {
    System.out.println("hello");
} catch (IOException e) {  // compilation error
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

*Edit by OP:* The main part of the answer is the fact that question examples work only for Exception class. Generally catching checked exceptions is not allowed in random places of the code. Sorry if I confused somebody using these examples.

Comment: Exactly, this rule existed long before try-multi-catch, probably since 1.0 (but certainly since 1.2).

Comment: Catching `Exception` does not catch everything. Catching `Throwable` catches everything.

Comment: You give an example with multiple exceptions. I'm okay with catching common parent - Exception if multiple exceptions are thrown and at least one of them is checked. But for all unchecked exceptions there is a common parent - RuntimeException. So I could still handle multiple unchecked exceptions with a single catch clause

Comment: @AdamSkywalker The rule is simple: if exception `E` can be thrown, any superclass of `E` can be caught. Why that rule was historically necessary has been made clear in the answers. The trouble with what you're suggesting is that the rules would become far more confusing and complicated to solve a problem that doesn't even exist.

Comment: AdamSkywalker: Yes, but language designers / compiler authors also need to keep things from getting more complicated than necessary. As @biziclop suggests, your proposed modification would solve a _very_ minor problem, yet complicate the rule and its implementation.

Comment: @TimBender: I wanted to focus on exceptions, but I agree that my original phrasing made it sound like exceptions are the only thing that can be thrown. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: Also, since anything could throw an `Error`, catching `Throwable` must always be allowed, and so the rule would look even more complicated: "You can catch any subclass of, and up to and including the lowest common ancestor of, all the exception types that might be thrown, and in addition, you can catch `Throwable`." - vs. "You can catch any subclass or superclass of what might be thrown."

Answer (score 11):

Java 7 introduced [more inclusive exception type checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow).

> However, in Java SE 7, you can specify the exception types FirstException and SecondException in the throws clause in the rethrowException method declaration. The Java SE 7 compiler can determine that the exception thrown by the statement throw e must have come from the try block, and the only exceptions thrown by the try block can be FirstException and SecondException.

This passage is talking about a `try` block that specifically throws `FirstException` and `SecondException`; even though the `catch` block throws `Exception`, the method only needs to declare that it throws `FirstException` and `SecondException`, not `Exception`:

> ```
> public void rethrowException(String exceptionName)
>  throws FirstException, SecondException {
>    try {
>      // ...
>    }
>    catch (Exception e) {
>      throw e;
>    }
>  }
> ```

This means that the compiler can detect that the only possible exception types thrown in `test` are `Error`s or `RuntimeException`s, neither of which need to be caught.  When you `throw e;`, it can tell, even when the static type is `Exception`, that it doesn't need to be declared or re-caught.

But when you *cast* it to `Exception`, this bypasses that logic.  Now the compiler treats it as an ordinary `Exception` which needs to be caught or declared.

The main reason for adding this logic to the compiler was to allow the programmer to specify only specific subtypes in the `throws` clause when rethrowing a general `Exception` catching those specific subtypes.  However, in this case, it allows you to catch a general `Exception` and not have to declare *any* exception in a `throws` clause, because no specific types that can be thrown are checked exceptions.

Comment: I understand why first code compiles and second does not. I think I should wrap the main question with bold font.

Comment: The main question is in the title - why even allow to catch Exception if we know it cant be thrown

Comment: I'm not convinced this fully explains what's going on, at a semantic level.  Yes, it describes behavior, but I'm not sold that this sort of thing is the true answer.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker It has always been possible to catch a superclass of all the possible exceptions that can be thrown, imagine a file manipulation method for example, which wraps code that can throw `FileNotFoundException` and `IIOException`. Before `try-multi-catch` the only way to deal with both was either to have two identical `catch` clauses, or catch a superclass of it, `IOException` for example. Or `Exception`. Both solutions are bad in a way, but the second one is slightly less bad.

Comment: The type `Exception` can be thrown. There is plenty of bad code out there that has methods which simply declare `throws Exception`. Exception itself could be constructed and thrown without further sub-classing it. As could `Throwable`, the super-type of all things that can be thrown.

Comment: @biziclop I wrote my thoughts about superclass catch under Aasmund answer

Comment: @TimBender And there are a few fairly legitimate cases, like in reflection.

Answer (score 7):

The issue here is that checked/unchecked exception limitations affect what your code is allowed to *throw*, not what it's allowed to *catch*.  While you can still *catch* any type of `Exception`, the only ones you're allowed to actually throw again are unchecked ones.  (This is why casting your unchecked exception into a checked exception breaks your code.)

Catching an unchecked exception with `Exception` is valid, because unchecked exceptions (a.k.a. `RuntimeException`s) are a subclass of Exception, and it follows standard polymorphism rules; it doesn't turn the caught exception into an `Exception`, just as storing a `String` in an `Object` doesn't turn the `String` *into* an `Object`.  Polymorphism means that a variable that can hold an `Object` can hold anything derived from `Object` (such as a `String`).  Likewise, as `Exception` is the superclass of all exception types, a variable of type `Exception` can hold any class derived from `Exception`, without turning the object *into* an `Exception`.  Consider this:

```
import java.lang.*;
// ...
public String iReturnAString() { return "Consider this!"; }
// ...
Object o = iReturnAString();
```

Despite the variable's type being `Object`, `o` still stores a `String`, does it not?  Likewise, in your code:

```
try {
    safeMethod();
} catch (Exception e) { // catching checked exception
    throw e; // so I can throw... a checked Exception?
}
```

What this means is *actually* "catch anything compatible with class `Exception` (i.e. `Exception` and anything derived from it)."  Similar logic is used in other languages, as well; for example, in C++, catching a `std::exception` will also catch `std::runtime_error`, `std::logic_error`, `std::bad_alloc`, any properly-defined user-created exceptions, and so on, because they all derive from `std::exception`.

tl;dr: You're not catching *checked* exceptions, you're catching *any* exceptions.  The exception only becomes a checked exception if you cast it into a checked exception type.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Please don't be flippant with people who only try to help you. The polymorphism argument is perfectly valid because at the heart of it `catch (Exception ex)` is pretty much like `Exception ex = ...`.