# JDK 1.7 onwards, throwing an exception object from catch block does not require a throws clause!!! Why is this so?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, java-7

I came across a weird scenario in java today while coding around. I have a try..catch block in my method which does not have any throws clause and I am able to throw the exception object caught in the catch block. **It is an object of the Exception class, hence it is not an unchecked exception.** Also, It is not printing the stacktrace if exception arises instead the exception is just getting swallowed.

Below is my code example,

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    public void test() {
        try
        {
            // Some code which may throw exception.
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Compiler should ask me to have a *throws Exception* in the signature, when I am throwing an exception object.
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

However, if I am throwing a new exception object instead of the caught exception object, compiler is asking me to have a throws clause in the method signature.

> N.B: I am facing this situation when running in Java 7 or 8.

I am wondering, where is the thrown object going to? Anyone with any idea on this please...

Comment: Related also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184092/why-is-catching-checked-exceptions-allowed-for-code-that-does-not-throw-exceptio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll see this if the code in the `try` block can't throw any *checked* exception. At that point, the compiler knows that the only kind of exception caught by the `catch` block has to be an unchecked exception, and so it can therefore be rethrown. Note that if you assigned a different value to `ex` within the `catch` block, the compiler would no longer be able to have that assurance. At the moment, `ex` is *effectively final*.

If you try to call something that is declared to throw a checked exception within the `try` block, the code will fail to compile as expected.

For example:

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    public void test() {
        try {
            foo();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void foo() throws java.io.IOException {
    }
}
```

Gives an error of:

```
ExceptionTest.java:12: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        throw ex;
        ^
```

As for where the exception "goes" - if the code in the try block throws an unchecked exception, it gets propagated as normal. Try this:

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }

    public static void test() {
        try {
            String x = null;
            x.length();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Running that gives the following output, as expected:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ExceptionTest.test(ExceptionTest.java:10)
        at ExceptionTest.main(ExceptionTest.java:4)
```

[JLS 11.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.2) documents what exceptions a statement can throw - your code will only compile if there are no checked exceptions that can be thrown.

Comment: see also here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Comment: It should be mentioned that `ex` must be *effectively final* for this to work, i.e. there must be no assignment to `ex` within the `catch` block.

Comment: @Holger: Will do, thanks.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your inputs. This really helped :)

Answer (score 1):

please check that you are really throwing an exception in the code. Otherwise the compiler will not care about catching the exception.

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    public void test() {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Error");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // My Compiler says that I don't catch the exception
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

Compiler: Error:(14, 13) java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your inputs. This really helped :)